# Ant - replace string in a hierarchy of files

Tags: ant

I have the following hierarchy of files

```
+ - A
    - a1.html
    - a2.html
+ - B
    + - C
       - c1.html
       - c2.html
    - b1.html
    - b2.html
```

I want to add a `<base>` tag to all the files (using `<replaceregexp>` or anything similar) so that for the files one level deep it will be `href=".."`, for two levels deep it will be `href="../.."` and so on.

What's the fastest/easiest way to do it in Ant?

Comment: Embed a scripting language within your ANT build. I'd recommend groovy http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a scripting language. Unfortunately there's no task/mapper to do this.